# For $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, if its Jacobian is singular at least one point, could its inverse be Lipschitz?

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions

Consider map $F \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, if there exists $x_0$ such that Jacobian $JF(x_0)$ is singular, we know that the inverse $F^{-1}$ may exist (e.g. $x\mapsto x^3$) and if it exists, it cannot be also in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (because it is not differentiable at $x_0$). But the question is, in this case, could the inverse be Lipschitz?

I can neither prove that the inverse is definitely not Lipschitz nor provide an example. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Is $x^\frac{1}{3}$ Lipschitz? (No it is not)

Comment: It has problems around $x = 0$

Comment: (he meant $x^{\frac13}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse is not Lipschitz. Assume:

- $F\colon\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$ has an inverse $G\colon\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$;
- $F(0)=0$;
- $DF(x_0)$ is not invertible.
  Then $G$ isn't Lipschitz near $0$.

**Proof.** Let $v\in\Bbb R^n$ be such that $DF(x_0)\cdot v=0$ (the existence of such $v$ follows from the assumption on $DF(x_0)$. This means that the directional derivative at $0$ in the direction $v$ is zero, that is
$$0= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(0+hv)-F(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(hv)}{h}.\tag{*}$$
Let $y_h:=F(hv)$. Then $y_h\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ and $hv=G(y_h)$. From (*) we get
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|G(y_h)-G(0)\|}{\|y_h-0\|} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|}{\|F(hv)\|}\cdot \|v\|\to\infty.$$